# How to define rectangle of visible children in Flash/AS3 ("real" element size)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, canvas, layout

I use `BitmapData.draw` to make a snapshot of a graph canvas. On the canvas located some children in random positions (including negative positions). I should to define in some way what rectangle bounds to shoot.

SO, for example, i have 3 nodes in the view (canvas):

- `{10x10, (-5; -3)}`
- `{20x20, (0; 0)}`
- `{30x30, (40; 40)}`

In this case bounds should be (-5; -3) (left top) to (70; 70) (right bottom).

Is there a way to define "real" element size, based on its children layout?

May be some methods from *Flex* framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DisplayObject.getBounds()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#getBounds%28%29) and [`DisplayObject.getRect()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#getRect%28%29) are the methods that you are looking for.

Both methods

> [Return] a rectangle that defines the boundary of the display object, based on the coordinate system defined by the `targetCoordinateSpace` parameter

The difference between them is:

> The `getBounds()` method is similar to the `getRect()` method; however, the Rectangle returned by the `getBounds()` method includes any strokes on shapes, whereas the Rectangle returned by the `getRect()` method does not.

If you use strokes, you probably want to use `getBounds()`

Comment: you can then merge all rectangles and get the values that should be used by the drawing Matrix.

Comment: @BotMaster or call the methods on the `DisplayObjectContainer` that contains the nodes. This would be possible if all nodes in the container should be included.

Comment: i tried getBounds(): left-top bound (negative) were correct, but right-bottom - too big. Probably, because i used parent width 100%. will check

Comment: @radistao I guess you solved the problem? Nice. Could you please add in a comment or by editing my answer how you did it exactly, given the obstacle that you encountered in your comment above.

Comment: actually, i resolved it an other way (the parent component had own implementation, based on iterating all children and calculating theirs x-y for left-top and (x + width)-(y+height) for right bottom. So, i have not checked the other approach. But your answer sounds quite reasonable, moreover guess getRect() works some similar way.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like in the most cases `getBounds()` and `getRect()` should work, but some times they may have problem calculating right-bottom corner, for instance, when component explicitly resized.

For my component I found already implemented method (this solution also ignores invisible children!):

```
public function calcDisplayObjecBoundingBox():Rectangle
  {
    var numChildren:int = this.numChildren;

    var result:Rectangle = new Rectangle( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
    var i:int = 0;
    var child:DisplayObject;

    if( numChildren > 0 )
    {

      //find first visible child and initialize rectangle bounds
      for( i = 0; i < numChildren; i++ )
      {
        child = this.getChildAt( i );

        if( child.visible )
        {
          result.left = child.x;
          result.top = child.y;
          result.right = child.x + child.width;
          result.bottom = child.y + child.height;
          i++;
          break;
        }
      }

      for( ; i < numChildren; i++ )
      {
        child = this.getChildAt( i );

        if( child.visible )
        {
          result.left = Math.min( result.left, child.x );
          result.right = Math.max( result.right, child.x + child.width );
          result.top = Math.min( result.top, child.y )
          result.bottom = Math.max( result.bottom, child.y + child.height );
        }
      }
    }
```

Probably, it works pretty much the same as for `getBounds()` and `getRect()`, but calculates right-bottom point by children, not the component itself.